# iterating through STRINGS in Python (3)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

: Write a   function,   named foldStrings(string1,  string2)    that    takes,  as  arguments,  two strings.        If
the two strings are equal   in  length, the function    returns a   string  that    is  formed  by  alternating characters  in  each    of the  two strings.        If  the two strings are not equal   in  length, the function    returns the string  “The    two strings are not 
equal   in  length.”

For example, >>>foldStrings(“abc”,  “def”)
should  return  the string  “adbecf” and >>>foldStrings(“a”,    “bc”)
should  return  the string  “The    two strings are not equal in length.”

This is what I have so far:

```
def foldStrings(str1, str2):
newStr = ""
counter = 0
if len(str2) == len(str1):
    while counter < len(str2):
        for element in str1:
            for index in str2:
                newStr = newStr + element
                newStr = newStr + index
                counter += 1
    return newStr
else:
    return "The two Strings are not equal in length"
```

and it prints this: 's1s2s3s4s5s6a1a2a3a4a5a6n1n2n3n4n5n6t1t2t3t4t5t6o1o2o3o4o5o6s1s2s3s4s5s6'
instead of this:
's1a2n3t4o5s6'

Comment: Right now, for every element in str1 it looks at *all* elements in str2. You only want it to look at the next element of str2. You only need 1 for loop over str1, not 2 loops over str1 *and* str2, because str1 and str2 are the same length.

Comment: exactly, and I'm not sure what to change as I've tried to change the placement. I've also tried to change the strings to a list but I was unable to do so without fully understanding how to iterate through strings as I need to be able to.

Comment: by the way this is just a practice assignment question in my intro to comp course. I'm reviewing simple things but for some reasons I get stuck on how to fix them.

Comment: @C.Helling error. sorry....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unnecessarily complicated the problem with three nested loops, when a single loop is required.

Replace:

```
while counter < len(str2):
    for element in str1:
        for index in str2:
            newStr = newStr + element
            newStr = newStr + index
            counter += 1
return newStr
```

With:

```
for index in range(len(str1)) :
    newStr = newStr + str1[index] + str2[index]

return newStr
```

In the original code, if the string length was for example 6, your code says:

```
 Repeat 6 times:
     for every character in str1
         for every character in str1
             do stuff
```

so that `do stuff` is executed 6 x 6 x 6 times! You only want to execute it 6 times suggesting a single loop.

What you were doing wrong was not a python specific issue, but  rather an issue with your algorithmic and logical thinking.  Mathematically the problem suggests a single iteration, while you had three - nested.  In this case you might have manually walked through the code or used a debugger to step through it to demonstrate flaw in thinking here.

Comment: I appreciate the cleaner version. Patrick has also provided similar a similar fix. If you wouldn't mind though, could you aid in helping fix my code in the structure that I was going for? As stated in another comment, I write these down on paper first and logically work it out and this seemed to work out mathematically but didn't translate well into the python language. If you can't come up with a fix to my code in the structure that is ok, now I'm just curious.

Best,
Santos

Comment: @srxprime13 : I have extended the answer, it is not that this is a "cleaner" solution; it is a mathematically consistent solution.  Creating a solution of complexity O(n-cubed) for an intrinsically O(n) problem makes no sense.  Your attempt makes little sense and cannot be adapted to work; it was just incorrect.

Comment: I really appreciate your candor and response. It helps a lot and answers literally weeks and weeks of problems I encountered with my algorithms I've been practicing with. I struggle with complexity in the algorithms and I will study up more about discerning between what's asked and what my mind is thinking lol!

Answer (score 0):

You can skip using a `counter` variable by using `range`

```
def foldStrings(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return "The two Strings are not equal in length" 
        # This should really be a raise ValueError("The two Strings are not equal in length")
    newStr = ''
    for i in range(len(str1)):
        newStr += str1[i] + str2[i]
    return newStr
```

Here's a slightly more compact way to replace the `for` loop

```
newStr = ''.join([x for pair in zip(str1, str2) for x in pair])
```

Comment: the for loop you've rewritten is a great replacement and cleaner...I just wonder what I was doing wrong and how I could fix my code in the way I was writing the structure. 

(When I tackle these small algorithms in my course, I write everything down first. Logically this worked in my head, but it didn't translate well into the Python programming language.)

Comment: @srxprime13 Let's say you have two lists `l1` with `m` elements and `l2` with `n` elements. If you do `for i in l1: for j in l2: print()`, you're going to end up with a total of `n*m` prints.  This is because for each of the `m` elements in `l1`, you're going to do `n` prints.  That's why the result you were getting cycles through all the characters of your second string before switching the character from your first string.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense now. I'm sorry you guys had to explain at such a basic level for me, but it helped! :) thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
#Simple way to do it 
def foldStrings(str1, str2):
    newStr = ""
    counter = 0
    if len(str2) == len(str1):
        while counter < len(str2):
            newStr = newStr + str1[counter] + str2[counter]
            counter += 1
        return newStr
    else:
        return "The two Strings are not equal in length"
```

Comment: The existing answers are already even simpler, and the OP has commented on both that what he is really looking for is an explanation of his flawed thinking rather then just a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Pratik Patil : Thanks Pratik, but as Clifford stated above.